# my default VPC does not have default subnet. how can i create the default subnet so that i can work on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, subnet

while i create EC2 machine it does not have public and private ip address because i also got the error no default subnet. how to resolve this. Please help me to get out of this
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Generally default subnet will be there. If not then you can go ahead create.

Comment: I am not getting how to create the default subnet. I tried alot to search but not getting. Please could you help me to get out of this

Comment: Somebody must have deleted it. Since the Default VPC is slightly 'magical', I suggest that you delete the VPC and then recreate the Default VPC via **Actions / Create default VPC**.

Comment: thanks for replying. I need to create it in free tier account and there is no option to create default VPC or default Subnet. there is the option create VPC only in place of default VPC. not able to understand what to do

Answer (score 3):

It appears from your first screenshot that the default behavior of your subnet is to not auto-assign a public IP address.

During instance launch (Step 3) you need to make sure that the option "Auto-assign Public IP" says Enable, you can find how [to do it in the documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-public-ip).

The error you're seeing doesn't have anything to do with the EC2 not having a Public IP.